# How to create menus like this with grammyjs (Telegram Bot)?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How can I create this menu with grammyjs?

[image]

This is my code. Now I send reply with the menu when user type "/main-menu" or when the user select the command "/main-menu" under Menu (blue button in picture).

```js
const menu = new Menu("main-menu")
  .text("A", (ctx) => ctx.reply("You pressed A!"))
  .text("B", (ctx) => ctx.reply("You pressed B!"));

bot.use(menu);

bot.command('main-menu', async (ctx) => {
  await ctx.reply('Here is your menu', { reply_markup: menu });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it's just easy

```
import {Keyboard} from "grammy";
bot.command("start", async (ctx) => {
const keyboards = new Keyboard().text(">").row().text("x").row().text("<");
await ctx.reply("Menu", {
reply_markup: keyboards, }); 
});
```

Keyboard is often used to create this kind of stuff in grammy.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvDJx.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).